# ionic 2/3: Is possible to hide the "div" of broken image?

Tags: html, image, ionic2, ionic3

I want to ask about hiding the "div" of broken image in ionic 3

I could hide the image using "onerror" but the place of div didn't hide. Here is my code:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of list;">
    <div style="width: calc(100%/2); float:left; position:relative; padding-bottom: calc(100%/2);">
        <img style="object-fit:cover; width: calc(100%); height: calc(100%); padding: 1px; position: absolute;" 
                    [src]="item.img" alt="Norway" 
                    onerror="this.style.opacity='0'" (click)="viewImage(item)"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

so, Is there any solution to fix and hide the div if the image broken ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onerror will not work in img tag try like this

```
<div *ngFor="let item of list;let i = index">
    <div style="width: calc(100%/2); float:left; position:relative; padding-bottom: calc(100%/2);">
        <img style="object-fit:cover; width: calc(100%); height: calc(100%); padding: 1px; position: absolute;"
                    [style.opacity]="error[i] ? 0 : 1"
                    [src]="item.img" alt="Norway" 
                    (error)="error[i] = true" (click)="viewImage(item)"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

In your **ts** file declare

```
 error:boolean[] = []
```

check the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-nbprdj?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)